# Reload script into div with ajax at the end of server side script

Tags: php, ajax

I have a shopping cart where `minicart.php` at the top of each page adds products sent to it with ajax load (POST) and update cart-sessions.

On one page another script further down the code, `cart_list.php` filters the cart amount for valid/invalid promotions. If it finds an invalid promotion it will delete it from the cart-session.

I reload minicart.php when cart_list.php is loaded but it doesent get the change. I also tried adding a timeout if it were a raceproblem.

```
("#cart").load("/cart_list.php", {amountchange:amount,key:key}, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#minicart").load("/minicart.php", {calledsolo:"true"});
            floatingBox();
        }, 500);
    });
```

If I put cart_list.php above mini_cart.php in the code it works but I prefer not to do that it possible, also I would like to understand why since mini_cart.php should reload indepentently anyway.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#minicart").load("/minicart.php", {calledsolo:"true"});
```

this call does not wait until it completes. so `floatingBox();` got called before the above ajax-call completes. try following:

```
("#cart").load("/cart_list.php", {amountchange:amount,key:key}, function() {
            $("#minicart").load("/minicart.php", {calledsolo:"true"}, function(){
                floatingBox();
            });
    });
```

Comment: ok I changed it but the problem seems to be that minicart.php gets called before cart_list.php. If I let cart_list change a product amount from 1 to 2 to 3. The minicart.php show 1 correctly on page load, but then 1 and 2, so it is trailing. In the end of cart_list.php the cart sessions are set. These are the values minicart use to update. Any suggestions to what the problem might be?